# Empty request body in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm having issues sending a post request to my api.
Both my iphone and my computer are on the same network, so I access the api the local public ip
In my app I set the App transport security to allow arbitrary urls.
The issue is the body is always empty.
I tried creating a localtunnel so I can access it via https but the body is till empty.

Here is my call

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "foo": "bar",
            "baz": ["a", 1],
            "qux": [
                "x": 1,
                "y": 2,
                "z": 3
            ]
        ]
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        Alamofire.request("my-url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers  ).responseJSON { (response) in
            debugPrint(response.result)
        }            
    }


}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just as a note - don't post your `Authorization` token.

Comment: You are not getting data from a proper URL. What does the `debugPrint(response.result)` give you?

Comment: The Autorization token is fake. When I run the request against https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts for instance, everything works fine. I get this ```SUCCESS: {
    "baz[]" =     (
        a,
        1
    );
    foo = bar;
    id = 101;
    "qux[x]" = 1;
    "qux[y]" = 2;
    "qux[z]" = 3;
}```

Comment: So everything appears to be working? Also, you shouldn't need to change App Transport Security settings, as you are communicating with `https` and I assume a safe internet protocol.

Comment: Calling an external https api works but calling my local server doesn't. The request is sent with an empty body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you retrieving params in your api?

If from the request body (i.e. not form the query string) then you should also pass the `encoding` argument to your Alamofire's request function as well with `JSONEncoding.default` value because by default the encoding is `URLEncoding.default` which means that parameters will be passed as query string.

So change this:

```
Alamofire.request("my-url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
    debugPrint(response.result)
}
```

To:

```
Alamofire.request("my-url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
    debugPrint(response.result)
}
```

---

> From Alamofire's doc

```
/// Creates a `DataRequest` using the default `SessionManager` to retrieve the contents of the specified `url`,
/// `method`, `parameters`, `encoding` and `headers`.
///
/// - parameter url:        The URL.
/// - parameter method:     The HTTP method. `.get` by default.
/// - parameter parameters: The parameters. `nil` by default.
/// - parameter encoding:   The parameter encoding. `URLEncoding.default` by default.
/// - parameter headers:    The HTTP headers. `nil` by default.
///
/// - returns: The created `DataRequest`.
@discardableResult
public func request(
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
    -> DataRequest
{
    return SessionManager.default.request(
        url,
        method: method,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: encoding,
        headers: headers
    )
}
```

Comment: The missing encoding was the issue. Thank you so much @artudev